# Collect interested data from tables in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have multi-tables in one sheet, how to collect my interested data from them.
for example, I just need the data of table1 column 3, and table2 column 2.
the size for both tables may be variate. I need collect the data into array for next processing.

Thanks.

[image: two tables in one sheet]

Comment: PS:the variate items for the two tables : 1.Size; 2. Start cell

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a way to restrict the tables in VBA, i.e. know in which row they start and of how many rows they consist. Because the tables can appear anywhere in the sheet with variate dimensions, there is no straight-forward way of extracting their data.

What I would suggest is to loop from the top to the lastrow of the sheet and on every row check if the table started and then in an inner loop iterate through the table rows until the table ends (i.e. an empty row is encountered).

The code might look similar to this (not tested):

```
Dim LastRow as Long, i as Long, k as Long
Dim sht as Worksheet
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Assuming the tables start in column A

For i=1 to LastRow
    If (sht.Range("A" & i) <> "" Then 'table is encountered
        k = i
        Do While sht.Range("A" & k) <> ""
             ... 'Get data from specific column
             k = k + 1
        Loop        
    End if
    i = k
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (necessary comments are in code):

```
Option Explicit
Sub CollectData()
    Dim table1Address As String, table2Address As String
    ' here you specify cells that are at the start of a column
    table1Address = "B2"
    table2Address = "C7"

    Dim firstCell As Range, lastCell As Range
    Dim table1Data, table2Data As Variant
    ' determine last cell in column and read whole column at once to an array variable
    Set firstCell = Range(table1Address)
    Set lastCell = Range(table1Address).End(xlDown)
    table1Data = Range(firstCell, lastCell).Value2

    Set firstCell = Range(table2Address)
    Set lastCell = Range(table2Address).End(xlDown)
    table2Data = Range(firstCell, lastCell).Value2

End Sub
```